# NetBeans doesn't work in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, netbeans

I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Then I installed NetBeans with `sudo apt-get install netbeans`. Now NetBeans doesn't work. It gives `cannot access java.lang` errors, such as:

```
cannot access java.lang  
 Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

[image: NetBeans doesn't work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have NetBeans 10 version in Ubuntu 18.04 but your JDK is either version 11 (*openjdk-11-jdk*) or version 8 (*openjdk-8-jdk*), so install latest NetBeans version and openjdk-11-jdk instead. Apache NetBeans can be installed from the terminal in Ubuntu 18.04 with the following command.

```
sudo snap install netbeans --classic
```

The *netbeans* snap package includes the Base IDE, Java Development Tools and Plug-in Development Tools.